# Переложить данные в двумерный массив

Tags: массивы, javascript

Не могу разобраться, как перебрать такой массив

```
[ { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'iv' },
  { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'iv' },
  { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'iii' },
  { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'iii' },
  { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'ii' },
  { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'ii' },
  { group: 'group-coupe', version: 'i' },
  { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'i' } ]
```

чтобы получить двумерный массив такого вида:

```
[ 
  [{ group: 'group-sedan', version: 'iv' },
  { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'iv' }],

  [{ group: 'group-sedan', version: 'iii' },
  { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'iii' }],

  [{ group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'ii' },
  { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'ii' }],

  [{ group: 'group-coupe', version: 'i' },
  { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'i' }]
]
```

Разложить его по полю version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sorted = {}
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i];
    var version = item.version;
    if (!(version in sorted)) {
        sorted[version] = [];
    }
    sorted[version].push(item);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как получить с этого массив именно такой, как в посте выше?  
Сейчас получаю такой объект массивов:

 [ 
  iv: [ 
   { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'iv' },
      { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'iv' }
     ],
   iii: [
    { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'iii' },
      { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'iii' }
     ],
    ii: [
     { group: 'group-wagon_5', version: 'ii' },
      { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'ii' }
     ],
    i: [
     { group: 'group-coupe', version: 'i' },
      { group: 'group-sedan', version: 'i' }
     ]
    ]

Comment: @webphp, это не так сложно сделать самому, как кажется

    var list = [];
    for (var i in sorted) {
        list.push(sorted[i]);
    }

Comment: я так и сделал, просто думал одним циклом как то обойтись, но так тоже пойдет

Comment: @webphp, к сожалению, нет, если сразу массивами оформлять, то их группу невозможно идентифицировать без проверки первого элемента, гемора будет больше, чем этот второй цикл сожрет ресурсов, в общем.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!